# Prefill Profile in create mode

Tags: profile, urls

What is the easiest was to prefill a field on a profile that is in create mode? I am linking from a drupal view where they click on the name of their organization and it will put the org name in the url. But i have been unable to use anything in the url to prefill the org name field on the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Which url parameters did you try? cid? contact_id? etc..
Another solution which is working is using Drupal CiviCRM Webforms and link to a prefilled webform from within your view.

Comment: I tried cid but in create mode you cannot use that because its creating a new contact. Drupal webforms do not allow for druapl registration. My goal is to let organizations register their username and password using this profile and not creating a new contact since they already exist in the system but dont have a druapl account.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i misunderstand but if you want the profile prefilled then you should change the word 'create' in the url to 'edit' - then a logged in user or person with a checksum will see their data in the fields.

Comment: I am trying to prefill the organization name field so that i do not get duplicate contacts. These organizations exist in my system now but do not have user accounts in drupal. I have a profile that allows users to register a user account for the organization but unless the org name is exact it will create a duplicate contact record.

Comment: So won't a Webform-CiviCRM solution work? Ie they enter their name, and they have an autocomplete option for their Organisation?

Comment: It would if i was able to assign a username and password for that user using a webform. Is that possible?

Comment: we came up with quite a convoluted work around - give civi contact a tag, set Drupal Rules to act on that Tag and create user account and if desired log them in instantly. I blogged about that here and the examples i attached may still be good to use. https://civicrm.org/blogs/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-single-or-multiple-contacts-civi-imports-and-webforms